# android keyboard showing numbers

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I am trying to show the android keyboard which shows only numbers and a decimal point it works fine in devices like Lenovo but it doesn't works in devices like Samsung. But when i installed an app the keyboard works same in both the above mentioned devices.
 I would like to know whether it is a custom keyboard or not.Even i have tried adding the code for the keyboard:

```
 amt.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
```

but it didn't works.I would like to know how to get the same keyboard as mentioned in the below image which works in all devices.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Use input type  android:inputType="number" in xml file to particular edit text.

Comment: I have given the input as android:inputType="numberDecimal" but it doesn't show in samsung devices

Comment: <EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123456789.," />

Comment: you will device specific and os version specific numeric keyboard. So there is change in numeric keyboard

Comment: did you solve ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

> By Xml

```
<EditText
android:inputType="numberDecimal|number"
android:digits="0123456789."
/>
```

> By Java

```
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);      //OR    
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

This may helps you.

Comment: see the second pic i am getting like this in samsung devices

Answer (score 2):

Try add comma ",". It may cause from different format of digits.

```
 <EditText
android:inputType="numberDecimal|number"
android:digits="0123456789.," />
```

Comment: see the second pic i am getting like this in samsung devices

Answer (score 2):

Try this line
amt.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

Comment: see the second pic i am getting like this in samsung devices

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to work through this problem at my job.  The Samsung Keyboard app has a single button for negative and decimal in some versions.  I don't have a screenshot at the moment, I can try to grab one tomorrow.  In order to get this button to show up when you select your EditText, on the XML side add:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
android:digits="0123456789.-"
```

Then in your Activity / Fragment with the EditText, find the EditText and apply regex to ensure it's a number.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text);

final String regex = "^\\-?(\\d*|\\d*\\.\\d+)$";

editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        //if we are adding text
        if (end > start) {
            String destinationString = dest.toString();
            String resultingTxt = destinationString.substring(0, dstart) + source.subSequence(start, end) + destinationString.substring(dend);
            // return null to accept the input or empty to reject it
            return resultingTxt.matches(regex) ? null : "";
        }
        // removing: always accept
        return null;
    }
}});
```

IMPORTANT:  Also make sure you don't have a NumberKeyListener attached to the EditText.  If you have a NumberKeyListener attached to the EditText the Samsung keyboard will hide the "-/." button you're trying to show.

Edit: If you don't want negative numbers you can also change the regex.

```
final String regex = "^(\\d*|\\d*\\.\\d+)$";
```

Answer (score 1):

add this attribute to you'r EditText in XML

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

try this

java

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: I have given the input as android:inputType="numberDecimal" but it doesn't show in samsung devices

Comment: see the second pic i am getting like this in samsung devices